# Using PHP $_GET in oci_parse

Tags: php

I need to use an `echo $_GET['id'];` in `oci_parse` but cannot seem to get it working. I have tried escaping it in ', " etc. but neither have worked.

**Code:**

```
  $stid = oci_parse($conn, "

    SELECT COLA, 
      (SELECT COLB FROM T2 WHERE T2.COLB = echo $_GET['id'];)
    FROM T1
    WHERE T1.COLA = echo $_GET['id'];

  ");
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple

Comment: first you have to do some validation and filtration on the $_GET array before using it inside the query .. then u can assign to a variable and use directly without echo inside the query

Comment: The sole purpose of `oci_parse()` (and what its examples in the manual page illustrate) is to use prepared statements. If you want to get hacked you don't need this function at all (although, using it incorrectly, is just as insecure as not using it at all). Whatever, I'm voting to close the question because you're disguising as advanced question your attempt to write PHP code without trying to learn the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT COLA, 
    (SELECT COLB FROM T2 WHERE T2.COLB = {$_GET['id']})
  FROM T1
    WHERE T1.COLA = {$_GET['id']}");
```

**Method - 2**

```
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT COLA, 
    (SELECT COLB FROM T2 WHERE T2.COLB = ".$_GET['id'].")
  FROM T1
    WHERE T1.COLA = ".$_GET['id']."");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do some validation before using it inside the query ..

```
if (ctype_digit($_GET['id'])){
    $dIdUser = $_GET['id'];

    $stid = oci_parse($conn, "
    SELECT COLA, 
      (SELECT COLB FROM T2 WHERE T2.COLB =$dIdUser ;)
    FROM T1
    WHERE T1.COLA = $dIdUser;

  ");

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need after query first execute the query?

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');

// Parse the statement. Note there is no final semi-colon in the SQL statement
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM employees');
oci_execute($stid);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

?>
```